# C++ how to use vector of reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, stdvector, reference-wrapper

I am totally new to reference_wrapper, so I need a very simple example to understand, please.

I declare two vectors:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vec_r;
```

I fill vec with some values, then I want vec_r to store references to each element of vec, and I want to assign values to vec_r in order to modify the values stored in vec. What should I do?

Comment: You could take a look at the example in the manual: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize `vec_r` with the contents of `vec`, using the appropriate constructor:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vec_r(begin(vec), end(vec));
```

It works because reference wrappers are constructible and assignable from the type they wrap.

Be warned however, that modifying `vec` after the fact can invalidate everything in `vec_r`. So tread carefully.